# How do I retrieve only next 3 videos on each Youtube API call?

Tags: typescript, angular5, youtube-data-api

This is the API call which I was using to get the list of maxresults.

```
var finalURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key="+this.API+"&channelId="+this.channelID+"&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults="+this.result+"";
```

but I dont know From the last videoId how do I make API call for next 3 videos eachtime?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `maxResults` before submitting your initial request; this will determine how many items you get back. In your case, set this to 3.

*After you submit your initial request*, if there are more results, you'll receive a `nextPageToken` in the response from the YouTube API. Include this with your next request as a `pageToken`, and it will return the next `maxResults` items it finds. (If there's no nextPageToken, then there are no more results.)

So your code might look something like this:

```
var maxResults = 3;

var finalURL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=' + this.API +
                '&channelId=' + this.channelID + 
                '&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=' + maxResults;

// this should be the response from your previous request
if (response.nextPageToken) { 
    finalURL += '&pageToken=' + response.nextPageToken;
}
```

See the YouTube API [documentation on pagination](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination) for full details.

Comment: Ya I took the nextPageToken from the first request and added it  for the next subsequent requests thanks but I solved it before your answer though